# Word Doc Text alignment

Tags: microsoft-word, documents, alignment

In a Word doc I am trying to aline both sides of the page to the sides (the left text to the left side and the right text to the right side. The text is separated on each line as it is a contents list for a book, with the titles needing to be aligned on the left and the page numbers on the right. It doesn't allow me to do this, if I align on the left side then the right side goes askew, and vice versa. It doesn't allow me to highlight each side separately. Does anyone know please how I can align both sides (as on a book contents & page numbers)?

Comment: It would be best if you add a screenshot of the page you're referencing (can be with sample data) for a clearer understanding of what you have and how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're actually trying to add a **Table of Contents** ("*book contents & page numbers*") you might be best served by the Work automatic Table of Contents option:
[image: Word TOC]

If you are just referring to that type of layout but for different text, this is accomplished using tabs:

1. **Click the small icon at the bottom-right of the Paragraph group.** Word displays the Paragraph dialog box:
   [image: Paragraph dialog box]
2. **Click the Tabs button** to see the Tabs dialog box:
   [image]
3. Add a right-aligned tab near the right edge of the line (depending on your page size and margin that should equals the opposite edge of where the left side text starts, so if you have a page 8.5" wide and the left side text/margin starts at 0.5" you would want this tab at 7.5")

   1. Enter 7.5 in the ***Tab stop position*** box
   2. In the ***Alignment*** area, **choose Right** (this tells Word that this will be a right-aligned tab, just like you want)
   3. (Optional) In the ***Leader*** area set which type of separator you want between the right and left texts (this is usually done for such text so that it's not difficult to see what right text goes with what left text)
   4. **Click on Set**
   5. **Click on OK** to close the Tabs dialog box
4. Now you can use the tab in the text by pressing the **Tab** key after the left text where you want the right text to start:
   [image: Using the tab stops]